# Generating constant coefficients for SERIESSUM formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm making a financial spreadsheet where I need to calculate the amount of money on an account on which it is deposited X dollars every month with yearly compound interest rate, at the end of Y years.

The formula resulted in

```
money = monthly deposit * 12 * (Tax + Tax^2 + Tax^3 + Tax^4 + ...)
```

i.e. if you deposit $100 every month on an account with 4% interest for 5 years, you'll get, at the end of those 5 years
100 * 12 * (1.04 + 1.04^2 + 1.04^3 + 1.04^4 + 1.04^5) = $6759.57

I'm not sure using Excel's `SERIESSUM()` formula is the best way to go, so correct me on that if it's not, but how do I generate a certain number of constant coefficients, like five 15000's for example, like so `{15000,15000,15000,15000,15000}` to insert into `=SERIESSUM(Interest;1;1;{15000,15000,15000,15000,15000})` so I can calculate the amount of dollars in the account after 5 years?

Answer (score 0):

I would use SUMPRODUCT()

```
=B3*12*SUMPRODUCT((1+B2)^ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & B1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. If you wanted to calculate the number of years until your account reached a certain amount, like $100.000,00 for example, how would you calculate that?

Comment: That is a new question.  New questions get new posts.  If this answered this question please mark it as such by clicking the check mark by the answer.